# Turpentine Varnish - Cart ist cached in one theme

Tags: magento-1.8, varnish

I've configured Turpentine Varnish Cache and on our store we run 2 themes, one with an ajax cart, which works fine, the other with a non-ajax cart which seems to be cached.

In our page.xml file for this theme, the cart is defined as:

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topcart" template="checkout/cart/topbar.phtml" />
```

in our header block

```
            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">               
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="directory/currency" name="store_currency_selector" as="store_currency_selector" template="directory/currency_top.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topcart" template="checkout/cart/topbar.phtml" />
        </block>
```

According to the Turpentine FAQ I should define it as follows to disable the block from being cached:

```
                <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topcart" template="checkout/cart/topbar.phtml">
                <action method="setEsiOptions">
                    <params>
                        <access>private</access>
                    </params>
                </action>
            </block>
```

But this has no effect at all.

In the turpentine_esi.xml it is defined as:

```
<reference name="cart_sidebar">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <access>private</access>
        </params>
    </action>
</reference>
```

How can I get this to work? Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below sorts the cart side bar but breaks the cart page so there must be a further call to cart page.

```
<reference name="cart_sidebar">
        <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                <access>private</access>
                <flush_events>
                    <sales_quote_save_after/>
                </flush_events>
                <registry_keys>
                    <current_category/>
                <registry_keys>

            </params>
        </action>
    </reference>
```